# Mariadb / Mysql "Authentication switch request" slows down PHP connections to mariadb server

Tags: mariadb, php

We switched our on premises MariaDB server to the Azure MariaDB managed service.
It runs on MariaDB 10.3.23 in which we cannot tune all server values.

While stress testing our PHP API application, we found that it takes twice as long to perform an API endpoint execution than on our on premises infrastructure. After having done some profiling with Datadog, it looks like we lost almost half of our time on "pdo construct" (i.e. connection to database). From the `tcpdump` output, it looks like we got a phase with : "Authentication switch request" and "Authentication switch response" almost lasting the time we lost. We do not see this phase in our on premises setup.

How can we speed this ?

PHP version is 7.2.

Comment: "How can we speed this?" Ask those who manage your managed service, I guess. Perhaps next time you will consider testing the new platform for performance before switching to it.

Comment: Some absolute measures may help. `skip-name-resolve` on the server side might help.

Comment: thanks for your help, we did not switched our production to it yet and this is a result from our performance test. DNS resolution looks fast too. Would you have another idea ?